# Abstracting implicit val of case class

Tags: scala

As I write programs in Scala with case classes, I've encountered a recurring pattern where I would want to put a creator of a case class as a parameter to it for future reference. I've learnt that we can capture this pattern by putting implicit value to a case class

```scala
abstract class MessageCreator
case class SomeMessage(s:String)(implicit val creator:MessageCreator)
class MyCreator extends MessageCreator { implicit val creator = this}
class ACreator extends MyCreator { def newMessage = SomeMessage("hello") }
```

Then, newMessage here will have member `creator` that refers to an instance of ACreator itself.

Now, I have a bunch of case classes that would do the same thing. My question is, how would you repeat this pattern without having to copy and paste `(implicit val creator:MessageCreator)` every time I want to define such case class?

I have tried defining an abstract class with implicit val, then inherit them from case class, but Scala was complaining that the implicit val from abstract class was not defined in the case class. Obviously, case class cannot be inherited.

If this cannot be done programmatically, I might start looking into writing a macro (which would be a fine solution). I want to make sure that I am not missing anything here.

Comment: IMHO this kind of parameters should be passed explicitly and only explicitly. If you really need this you can use companion objects as factories to pass creator parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I have a companion object with, say `def apply(implicit val creator:MessageCreator) {...}`, how do I make case classes inherit such class with companion object?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about it the domain I'd ask some questions along the lines of:

1. Why can't your factory be your companion object? For a case class this already is explicitly so due to the language and it's compiler. If you need another I'd overload the apply.
2. Why does your class need the ability to create more of itself? Isn't that partially what "copy" is for (and by partial I mean without all fields replaced.)

The season I'd ask these questions is that, devoid of context, it sounds like you've introduced additional complexity without much benefit.

Finally if you're implicitly passing state I'd caution you against it. This can lead to all sorts of issues and problems down the line. Implicits are wonderful unless they cause a bug, in which case that bug becomes difficult to decipher and track down. I'd almost go so far as to say you should only use implicit for type classes

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer

1. Granted, I could achieve similar thing with companion object. But what value does it give? And it doesn't seem to give inheritance that I want (or does it?)

Comment: 2. Well, let me argue from the first principle. If a programmer is repetitively writing the same block of code for the same concern over and over, it is only natural that he/she thinks of ways of abstracting it so that he/she does not need to give names to such thing as implicit 'creator' value and rely on naming convention for the shared concern of different entities. Now, had Scala been homoiconic language , it would be a very natural thing to implement. With the recent addition of macro to Scala, I can do this with macro. The question is, can it be done within semantics of Scala?

Comment: And w.r.t. your last comment, I am implicitly passing in a reference to a class. I haven't mentioned in OP but the context of the question is that I want to pass around senders of messages when actors send out message to one another so I can track down original sender of the actor. To me that does not sound like passing around states. But of course, one can abuse this and go on to produce side effects on the original sender, which is undesirable.